# How to restore ntfs partition table in freebsd

Tags: freebsd, data-recovery

I accidentally deleted my partition table(MBR + NTFS) on my old disk through:

```
gpart delete -i ada3
gpart destory ada3
```

Which contains all files on it. How can I restore these data on this disk?

Comment: I took the disk out and used windows version of testdisk to restore the partition table. The testdisk under freebsd don't seem to be able to recognize the disk. Can somebody suggest a better way doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After partitioning a new drive with an MBR, you should run `gpart backup`, save the output and store it somewhere safe. Then you can restore it with `gpart restore`.

If you use a GPT, the backup is made automatically. You can then use `gpart recover` to recover it.